# How to swap out the driver of a network device on a running Debian Linux box?

Tags: debian, drivers, devices, ethernet, modprobe

I've got an embedded/headless Debian Linux box which boots from a read-only filesystem image.  The configuration is set up so that I can (seemingly) write to the filesystem, but any changes to the filesystem do not actually get written to the flash device and thus do not survive a reboot.

This box has an on-motherboard Ethernet interface (Intel 82571EB) that uses the e1000e Linux driver:

```
root@embedded:~# lspci -v
[...]
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 PT Dual Port Server Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at fc600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
[...]
```

As a way to understand the e1000e driver a bit better (and perhaps find and fix a bug that I suspect might be lurking in it), I've compiled my own instrumented version of the e1000e.ko kernel extension file and I would like to try it out.

I can scp my e1000e_instrumented.ko file to the Linux box, but I'm not sure what the proper way is to disassociate the OS's built-in e1000e driver from the 82571EB Ethernet controller and then tell Linux to use my custom .ko file instead.  (If it was a desktop-style Linux PC, I think I could do it by copying my file over the existing /lib/modules/3.8.13/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko file and then rebooting... but on this machine any changes I make will go away when I reboot the machine, so I think I need a technique that does not involve a reboot)

What is the proper way to do this in Debian Linux?  As an initial test, I tried:

```
modprobe -r e1000e ; modprobe e1000e
```

... just to see if I could remove the built-in driver and then re-load it again, but doing that just kills the networking on the Linux box and doesn't bring it back.

Comment: alternatively, if your machine has a second NIC (that uses a different driver) you could ssh in over that while working on the e1000e.  some PCI-e NICs are quite cheap, $10 or so.  as are many USB NICs.  would be best to use a different IP subnet (e.g. a private subnet used only by the ssh client and ssh server) on the second NIC to avoid routing complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `ifup -a` to bring up the network interfaces after modprobing e1000e.  Adding some small delays with `sleep 2` won't hurt either.

So, try:

```
ifdown -a ; sleep 2 ; modprobe -r e1000e ; sleep 2; modprobe e1000e ; sleep 2; ifup -a
```

Comment: Please note that this assumes that the vendor of that particular system has properly configured the network interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` (instead of a custom hack like, say, `dhclient eth0` in `rc.local`). You'd think that that would be a reasonable assumption, but I've tripped over similar assumptions.